# Web Api User.Identity.Name null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

не передаются куки для web api, для mvc все работает.

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, true);

запрос с клиента передается через jquery ajax

```
        var serviceId = $('#Id').val();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "Number" })' + '?serviceId=' + serviceId
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

вот из-за этого не работало